# run windows service from asp.net web page

Tags: asp.net, windows-services

i have a web page written in vb, i need to start a windows service that will be installed in the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to add a reference to the System.ServiceProcess assembly.  The following code gives you roughly what you want to do (I am using a Label control called **messageLabel** in the following):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class StartService : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string serviceName = "Remote Registry";
        try
        {
            StartServiceByName(serviceName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            messageLabel.Text = ex.ToString().Replace("\r\n", "<BR>");
            return;
        }
        messageLabel.Text = String.Format("Service {0} started.", serviceName);
    }

    private void StartServiceByName(string serviceName)
    {
        ServiceController serviceController = new ServiceController(serviceName);
        serviceController.Start();
    }
}
```

However, there is a further thing - you need to have the web server have permission to change this service - which is something that normally can be only done with Administration rights.

Answer (score 0):

haven't tested.

pleas try if works or not. you could add following code in btn click event.

```
dim controller as new ServiceController

controller.MachineName = "." //try the machine name
controller.ServiceName = "service name"
dim status as string = controller.Status.ToString

' Stop the service
controller.Stop()

' Start the service
controller.Start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the permissions that the web site account has, you can start / stop services.

In addition to what others have answered, you can shell out `NET START` with the appropriate parameters.

You can also do this for remote computers as long as the permissions are granted (I think it has to be a domain account for this).